# investigate the influence of the collector current on the base current in an n-p-n transistor

Tags: transistors, base

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa8nup.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image][image]

why does the base current decreases as the collector current increases?
And as the base current increases the collector current also increases. Why and how?

Thank you. I really need some help and understanding in this area.

Comment: You have to show us the schematic you're using to evaluate this. There is an Rv mentioned, I do not know how you're using it. Also, beta = Ic/Ib must be constant over a large range of currents. I suspect your Vce is not constant and that could explain the results you see.

Comment: I think your transistor is hot.
When the temperature increases, the gain of the transistor increases.
Turn off the circuit. Wait until the cooling of the transistor. Include a scheme for a short time. Quickly make measurements.

Comment: You really need to narrow this down and show what understanding you already have.

Comment: user87932, because you did not mention HOW you have changed the currents, I have assumed that you did increase VCE, correct?

Comment: We apply a DC voltage Vdc = 20 v to the circuit, our base current is measured with interrupted collector line (potentiometer removed) and entered in table 8.1 for Ic=0. Then the potentiometer is inserted and used to set the collector current values specified to Table 8.1.The dependence of the base current om the collector current (at constant base/ emitter voltage) is shown in graph form in Figure 8.3. Then the circuit is modified as shown in figure 8.2.

Comment: The base current is altered with the potentiometer according to the values specified in Table 8.2, the corresponding collector current values measured was entered in the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have measured the results of the so-called **Early effect**. Increasing the voltage Vce (and, thus, the voltage Vcb for a fixed Vbe) causes an increase in Ic and a (small) decrease of Ib. This is because the sum of both (Ic+Ib=Ie) must be constant (Vbe determines Ie and remains constant).

Why does Ic increase and Ib decrease? Answer: Because an increased Vcb increases the width of the depletion layer region and a corresponding width reduction of the B-E junction (which allows the base current). Hence, more charged carriers arrive at the collector (Ic increases, Ib decreases correspondingly). This effect is responsible for the well-known finite slope of the Ic=f(Vce) characterisics.

For reducing Ic back to the former value you must somewhat reduce Vbe. If the Ic increase was caused by temperature the Vbe reduction value is -2mV/K.

Comment: At table 8.1 I calculated the Beta(B) where B=Ic/Ib, i noticed that Beta is increasing as the current in the terminal c (collector) increases. Then the Beta on the table 8.2 is decreasing as the current in terminal B (Base) increases.